# Android: How to delete all the Elements of a XML-File programmatically

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-constraintlayout

as the title states, how to delete all the elements of any given XML-File.
Let's say we have the following XML-File: example.xml:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/idExample">

<Button
        android:id="@+id/beispiel2"
        android:onClick="onSelectDas"
        android:text="Check"
/>

<Button
        android:id="@+id/beispiel2"
        android:onClick="onSelectDas"
        android:text="Check"
/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Question:** How to delete two Button Elements from the example.xml - programmtically?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void removeDirectChildren( Node parent )
{
  NodeList childNodes = parent.getChildNodes();
  while ( childNodes.getLength() > 0 )
  {
    parent.removeChild( childNodes.item( 0 ) );
  }
}
```

and you call it with the root element.

Answer (score 0):

Call [`removeAllViews()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup#removeAllViews()) on the *ConstraintLayout*.

> Call this method to remove all child views from the ViewGroup.

```
contraintLayout.removeAllViews()
```